# Opening Java enum method declarations in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, method-declaration

Eclipse provides a feature to open the declarations of fields, invoked methods etc.

(***F3*** or ***Right click => Open declaration*** or ***Ctrl + click on the invoked method***)

However, in the case of enum methods this feature doesn't function, e.g. 
`MyEnum.values();` is called somewhere in my code and trying to open the declaration of `values()` with the combinations denoted above doesn't work obviously.

Why doesn't Eclipse open the declaration of such enum methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't Eclipse open the declaration of such enum methods?

Because they're not declared in source code at all. They're automatically supplied by the compiler - where would you expect to be taken? Ctrl-clicking on `MyEnum` (rather than the `values()` method) should open the enum with no problems though.

From [section 8.9.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3):

> The members of an enum type E are all of the following:
>
> - ...
> - The following implicitly declared methods:
>
>   ```
>   /* javadoc... */
>   public static E[] values();
>
>   /* javadoc... */
>   public static E valueOf(String name);
>   ```

Note that the normal "go to declaration" techniques should work for any methods which genuinely exist in source code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course, MyEnum declaration gets open with no problems. I didn't know that enum methods aren't declared in source code. Can you also point to the other compiler-supplied code in Java other than enums please?

Comment: @Juvanis: There isn't a lot - parameterless constructors spring to mind, and nested classes can involve some synthesis in order to propagate the enclosing member, give access to private members etc.

Comment: So we have a public API without Javadoc? Ugly. IDEs should at least try to mixin the Javadocs at JLS 8.9 into that synthetized methods.